# How do I force the browser to get an updated PDF file generated from an SSRS report?

Tags: pdf, caching, reporting-services, browser, temporary-files

I have a web page that downloads a pdf version of an ssrs report through a link. However when I make changes to the data, the browser pulls up the same pdf file as before without the updated information (the pdf file stored in the temp folder). If I then go to another browser and download the PDF I get the new version, but the other browser still gets the old version. How can I force the browser to download a new version of the pdf report?

The url I use to create the pdf is below:

http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/MyReport/&rs:Command=Render&ReportID=123456&rs:Format=PDF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the clearsession parameter to get a fresh pdf with updated information,
it looks like this in the url:

http://servername/ ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/MyReport/ &rs:Command=Render&ReportID=123456 &rs:Format=PDF &rs:ClearSession=true

[Managing Report Sessions on a URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256628(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: Great tip. I think I'll add that option for every execution.

Answer (score 0):

Any one of the flowing will work.

- [Modify the report viewer .aspx to set
  the content expiration to immediate.](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/2009-04/msg00068.html)
- [Modify IIS to set the content
  expiration to immediate.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true)
- Configure your browser to check for
  newer version of the page or to not
  cache pages.

Comment: @CptSkippy: Not necesarely. IE 6 doesn't mind of the Context-Expiration header and happily caches all it can.

Comment: @voyager : I think in the past there was confusion about what settings IE respected but Microsoft has clearly defined IE's behavior and my examples work when setup properly (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067).